# Pygame Surface Scaling Issue

Tags: python, pygame, scale, pygame-surface

I have a problem in Pygame where, if I scale a *Surface* with a grid (which is displayed correctly in the first image) to a **smaller size**, I experience a strange bug where the lines are not drawn properly. As far as I understand, when I draw something on a dummy Surface with certain dimensions, I should be able to draw anything relative to these dimensions and when I scale it, everything inside should scale as well, but in my case, it's not working that way. Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 320
TILE_SIZE = 32

pygame.init()

# 16:9 R
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((192, 108), pygame.RESIZABLE)
s = pygame.Surface([WIDTH, HEIGHT])

pygame.display.set_caption("Grid")

def draw_grid():

    s.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for v in range((WIDTH // TILE_SIZE) + 1):
        # vertical
        pygame.draw.line(s, (0, 0, 0), (TILE_SIZE * v, 0), (TILE_SIZE * v, HEIGHT))
        # horizontal
    for h in range((HEIGHT // TILE_SIZE) + 1):
        pygame.draw.line(s, (0, 0, 0), (0, TILE_SIZE * h), (WIDTH, TILE_SIZE * h))

def draw_bg():
    temp_frame = pygame.transform.scale(s, (192, 108)) # bug
    screen.blit(temp_frame , (0, 0))

    # screen.blit(s, (0, 0)) would work properly


while True:
    draw_grid()
    draw_bg()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried changing `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` variables in `draw_grid` but that doesn't seem to be issue here

Comment: There seems to be a bug in `draw_bg()` where it is scaling and blitting a temporary Surface instead of s directly.

Comment: Is there a way how to fix it?

Comment: There is no bug at all. A surface consists of pixels. When a surface is scaled down, some of the pixels are simply thrown away. You can try  [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale), but then you will get blurred lines.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Amazing, that seems to do the trick. Could you elaborate further tho? Why is it happening (that pixels are getting discarded), and what are the benefits of using smoothscale over normal scaling? Thanks in advance!

Comment: e.g. If you have a surface with 4x4 (16) pixel and you want scale it down to 2x2 (4) pixel, then you have to discard 12 pixel. Alternatively you can interpolate the colors of the pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surface consists of pixels. When a surface is scaled down with [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale), some of the pixels are simply thrown away. [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) uses a different algorithm and does not throw away pixels, but interpolates them:

<s>`temp_frame = pygame.transform.scale(s, (192, 108))`</s>

```py
temp_frame = pygame.transform.smoothscale(s, (192, 108))
```